# Can't get the correct pixel from an image returned from camera

Tags: android, kotlin, android-imageview, dimensions, onactivityresult

I'm trying to load in an imageview an image returned from the camera of the device and gett the colors of the pixel I touch.

I tried scaling the image in the xml file, but when I do although I see the image fit in the imageview the touchlistener works at the original dimensions of the image.
If I don't scale it I see only the part of the image that fits the imageview and the touchlistener get the actual pixel.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath)
        ivCamera.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
        ivCamera.setOnTouchListener { view, motionEvent ->
            val bmp = (ivCamera.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
            val pixel = bmp.getPixel(motionEvent!!.x.toInt(), motionEvent.y.toInt())
            pixelRed = Color.red(pixel)
            pixelGreen = Color.green(pixel)
            pixelBlue = Color.blue(pixel)
            tvColor.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(pixelRed!!, pixelGreen!!, pixelBlue!!))
            true
        }
    }
}


   <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="0.7"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:id="@+id/ivCamera"
           android:scaleType="matrix"
           android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
           android:layout_margin="10dp"
           android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
           android:adjustViewBounds="true"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           android:contentDescription="PicureTaken"/>
```

If I scale the image in the xml file, I see the image fitted in the imageview but the touchlistener works at the original dimensions of the image.
If I don't scale it I see only the part of the image that fits the imageview and the touchlistener get the actual pixel.

Comment: by "scale it", do you mean with the code: `scaleType="matrix"`?

Comment: Well as it's obvious I'm not a "pro" so with google helping what came closer to what I wanted to do was scaleType.

Comment: hmm? I was merely asking a question to help understand so I can reply properly

Comment: Didn't intend to insult you, just stating that the approach could be totally wrong cause of it

Comment: no worries, gave an answer but its a strange one! not my usual area of knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be one of those crazy scenarios where you are setting the touch listener `ivCamera.setOnTouchListener` before the XML scale type has took effect `ivCamera.setImageBitmap`. i.e. it sets a touch on the original dimensions before the `scaleType` comes into effect.

You could use a layout listener to set the touch listener after the ImageView has finished inflating.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener

```
ivCamera.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ivCamera.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

            if(ivCamera.getDrawable() != null) {
                  ivCamera.setOnTouchListener {
                  // etc
                  // ...
            }

        }
    });
```

This isn't an answer I am confident in, but an answer. :-) sorry it's so horrible / such a hack!

---

Looking at this again...

```
 val bmp = (ivCamera.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
 val pixel = bmp.getPixel(motionEvent!!.x.toInt(), motionEvent.y.toInt())
```

You get the bitmap back off of the ImageView, then call `getPixel` however clearly `.bitmap` is returning you the original sized bitmap even though you scaled it (for the view) with `scaleType`.

My recommendation would either be to translate the x/y co-ordinates of the touch event to the scaled image size.

Or scale the bitmap yourself before you call `setImageBitmap` on the ImageView. That way you don't need to translate the x/y.

Comment: ok, I will give it a try first thing in the morning, too tired to change code now

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the answer here.

Comment: @GiorgosKavalieratos updated my answer, sorry I don't give a code solution, but I think that's definetely the way to fix it. (For example with `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap`)

Comment: Yup, you are right. I can't get dimensions since they are set after the image is loaded, so I get 0. But translation worked fine. Thank you